# Undefined method 'column' mongoid and bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, mongoid

I have a scaffold aplication with mongoid and did:
rails g bootstrap:install

but when I put:

```
rails g bootstrap:themed Contratos
```

I have this Error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.6/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/themed_generator.rb:59:in block in columns': undefined method 'columns' for Contrato:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the source code of the themed generator:

```
  def columns
    excluded_column_names = %w[id created_at updated_at]
    if defined?(ActiveRecord)
      rescue_block ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid do
        @model_name.constantize.columns.reject{|c| excluded_column_names.include?(c.name) }.collect{|c| ::Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute.new(c.name, c.type)}
      end
    else
      rescue_block do
        @model_name.constantize.fields.collect{|c| c[1]}.reject{|c| excluded_column_names.include?(c.name) }.collect{|c| ::Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute.new(c.name, c.type.to_s)}
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem you are facing is that your application defines ActiveRecord but your ar using Mongoid.

You should replace the line `require 'rails/all'` in your `application.rb` file for the following lines:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

More information about Mongoid installation in: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html.

Comment: Ok, you are right, but even removing the require 'rails/all' this error still happens! I built my rails app with -O !

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a "columns" class method to your Mongoid models so that the generator still responds correctly:

```
def self.columns
  self.fields.collect{|c| c[1]}
end
```

This approach was based on Nicolas Garnil's response and worked for me.